# Multiple ways to write driver of Hadoop program - Which one to choose?

Tags: hadoop

I have observed that there are multiple ways to write driver method of Hadoop program.

Following method is given in [Hadoop Tutorial by Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html)

```
 public void run(String inputPath, String outputPath) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    // the keys are words (strings)
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    // the values are counts (ints)
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(inputPath));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(outputPath));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
```

and this method is given in `Hadoop The Definitive Guide 2012` book by Oreilly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  if (args.length != 2) {
    System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
  Job job = new Job();
  job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
  job.setJobName("Max temperature");
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
  job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
  job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

While trying program given in Oreilly book I found that constructors of `Job` class are deprecated. As Oreilly book is based on Hadoop 2 (yarn) I was surprised to see that they have used deprecated class.

I would like to know which method everyone uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the former approach.If we go with overriding the run() method, we can use hadoop jar options like -D,-libjars,-files etc.,.All these are very much necessary in almost any hadoop project.
Not sure if we can use them through the main() method.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly different to your first (Yahoo) block - you should be using the ToolRunner / Tool classes which take advantage of the GenericOptionsParser (as noted in Eswara's answer)

A template pattern would be something like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class ToolExample extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // old API
        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(getConf());

        // new API
        Job job = new Job(getConf());

        // rest of your config here

        // determine success / failure (depending on your choice of old / new api)
        // return 0 for success, non-zero for an error
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new ToolExample(), args));
    }
}
```