# Convert HDFS SequenceFile from SnappyCodec to DefaultCodec

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Given a choice, I'd love something I can run from Hadoop shell vs an MR job.  I only have a few files that need to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code that is untested but should do the trick (obviously the file names are made up - sequence files don't typically have extensions):

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

Path inputPath = new Path("part-r-00000.snappy");
Path outputPath = new Path("part-r-00000.deflate");
FSDataOutputStream dos = fs.create(outputPath);

SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, inputPath,
        conf);
Writable key = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
        reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
Writable value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
        reader.getValueClass(), conf);

CompressionCodecFactory ccf = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
CompressionCodec codec = ccf.getCodecByClassName(DefaultCodec.class
        .getName());
SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, dos,
        key.getClass(), value.getClass(), reader.getCompressionType(),
        codec);

while (reader.next(key, value)) {
    writer.append(key, value);
}

reader.close();
dos.close();
```

You should also acquire the configuration via the `ToolRunner` / `Tool` pattern - here's a similar question that outlines it incase its a new principal to you:

- [Multiple ways to write driver of Hadoop program - Which one to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184227/multiple-ways-to-write-driver-of-hadoop-program-which-one-to-choose/16191041#16191041)